# Custom keyboard layout AltGr binds don't work in certain programs

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I made a custom keyboard layout to make a game easier to play by re-mapping the numeric keys to AltGr+Q,W,E,etc., but I've now discovered that while that works properly while typing in any program, the game doesn't recognize it. Why is this and is there any way around it?
Sidenote: confirming that I can't map anything to work the same as the enter key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have expected it to work, because games use scan codes, not keyboard layouts.

A keyboard layout is involved only when an app requires to translate a key-tapping event into a letter. The app gets the scan code corresponding to the physical key pressed, then maps it over to the keyboard layout to find out which letter should be typed. Video games on the other hand, skip this conversion because knowing just which physical key is press is enough for them.

Theoretically, however, it is possible to write an app that intercepts all keyboard inputs, replace certain key-tapping events with others and resend them back to whatever app was receiving it. However, I don't know if such an app exists. (Even if it did, I probably couldn't suggest it here, because software suggestions are out of the scope of this website. But [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) can help you with that.)